# Braintree v.zero without SSH

Tags: security, paypal, ssh, braintree

I am currently integrating a payment system to my website. I am interested by the "Braintree v.zero" offer of PayPal, but I am worry about the security.
I don't have any https connection for my website, "Braintree v.zero" will still be secure without it?

I know that my question is very specific, hope someone will have an answer for me :)

SeeoX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it absolutely will not be secure.  Without https, anybody can eavesdrop or modify data transmitted to your website including payment information.  They can also steal credentials and take over accounts.

Why do you not have an https connection?  If it is a cost concern, then you might check out [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (this is not an endorsement of them, just a note that you can get certificates for free).

Comment: Thanks :)  
It's what I was afraid of, but I was incapable of finding any recommendation about it on their website or on the web. Strange...